# Knex.js - TypeError: db(...).return(...).insert is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I am getting the error : *TypeError: db(...).return(...).insert is not a function*

For some reason the code runs `'db.select('*')'` without a problem but when it gets to

```
'db('courses')
  .return('*')
  .insert({'
```

it gives the error : TypeError: db(...).return(...).insert is not a function.

I can not figure out what is going on, I've been stuck on this for 4 hours.

My code sample :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');


const db = knex({
  client:'pg',
  connection:{
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    port:'5432',
    user:'postgres',
    password:'',
    database:'YouList'
  }
})


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

db.select('*').from('users').then(data => {
  console.log(data,'oia a data ai');
});

/*testando sem API*/ 
db('courses')
  .return('*')
  .insert({
    title: "o grande curso",
    description : "uma introducao aos ventos do leste",
    user_id : 78,
    urlimage : "https://i.imgur.com/TiavcG9.jpg",
    created : new Date()
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .then(user => {
    res.json(user[0]);
  })
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `return` and not `returning`. You should also chain it off of `insert`, rather than having it before.  Makes it a bit more idiomatic.

So just switch it around...

```
db('courses')      
  .insert({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
  .returning('*')
```

Comment: great tip my friend!